# boostrap установить картинки

Tags: html, css

Помогите, как сжать картинки,чтобы все стало на свои места

```css
.servises {
 padding-top: 140px;
 position: relative;
}

.title h2 { 
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #111;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;    
}

.title p {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 70px 75px;
 display: block;
 max-width: 760px; 
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #777;
    font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0;    
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform:none;    
}

.nav {  
    padding: 75px 0 40px;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.nav-tabs {
float: none;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs li {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav tabs ul {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 285px;
 margin-right: 285px; 
}

.sketch_block { 
 display: block; 

}
```

```html
<section class="section-light portfolio ">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="title text-center">
              <h2>Portfolio</h2>         
                <p>In auctor ex id urna faucibus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus ligula semper metus pellentesque mattis. Maecenas  volutpat, diam enim sagittis quam, id porta quam. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh volutpat, accumsan purus. </p>             
            </div>
              <ul class=" nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#portfolio-tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">          
                All Works </a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                
                Branding</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                
                 Design</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                
                Photography</a></li>
             </ul>
              <hr>
              <div class="tab-content">
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="services-tab1">           
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12"class="portfolio-title text-center">
              <div class="row">          
                <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4 pull-left">
                  <img src="img/sketch1.png" alt"">
                </div>
                <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
                  <img src="img/sketch2.png" alt"">
                </div>
                <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4 pull-right">
                  <img src="img/sketch3.png" alt"">
                </div>
                <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4 pull-left">
                  <img src="img/sketch4.png" alt"">
                </div>
                <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
                  <img src="img/sketch5.png" alt"">
                </div>
                <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4 pull-right">
                  <img src="img/sketch6.png" alt"">
                </div>
              </div>                  
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <hr>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавить изображениям класс `img-responsive`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
<section class="section-light portfolio ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title text-center">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>         
      <p>In auctor ex id urna faucibus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus ligula semper metus pellentesque mattis. Maecenas  volutpat, diam enim sagittis quam, id porta quam. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh volutpat, accumsan purus. </p>             
    </div>
    <ul class=" nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#portfolio-tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">          
        All Works </a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

        Branding</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

        Design</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

        Photography</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="services-tab1">           
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-title text-center">
      <div class="row">          
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Cicada_BroodXIII_1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.smith-mountain-lake-visitor-center.com/images_wallpaper/wide_screen_wallpaper/W4V4B4131_RONEY_PHOTOGRAPHY.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.rachaelray.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MTI5OTcwMTkyNzEyMjQzNjc4-1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>       
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/5a/13/ac/5a13ac1f76f5d033bb03b67412572961.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/17/98/e0/1798e0883d42d34ae640a863e2d3126f.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://friendlysiberia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/DSC00738-1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <hr>
```

Без пробелов между картинками:

```css
.portfolio .sketch_block {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
<section class="section-light portfolio ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title text-center">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>         
      <p>In auctor ex id urna faucibus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus ligula semper metus pellentesque mattis. Maecenas  volutpat, diam enim sagittis quam, id porta quam. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh volutpat, accumsan purus. </p>             
    </div>
    <ul class=" nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#portfolio-tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">          
        All Works </a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

        Branding</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

        Design</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio-tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

        Photography</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="services-tab1">           
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-title text-center">
      <div class="row">          
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Cicada_BroodXIII_1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.smith-mountain-lake-visitor-center.com/images_wallpaper/wide_screen_wallpaper/W4V4B4131_RONEY_PHOTOGRAPHY.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.rachaelray.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MTI5OTcwMTkyNzEyMjQzNjc4-1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>       
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/5a/13/ac/5a13ac1f76f5d033bb03b67412572961.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/17/98/e0/1798e0883d42d34ae640a863e2d3126f.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://friendlysiberia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/DSC00738-1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <hr>
```

А еще лучше использовать bootstrap 4:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
  
<section class="section-light portfolio ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title text-center">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>         
      <p>In auctor ex id urna faucibus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus ligula semper metus pellentesque mattis. Maecenas  volutpat, diam enim sagittis quam, id porta quam. Sed id dolor consectetur fermentum nibh volutpat, accumsan purus. </p>             
    </div>
    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab" aria-controls="all" aria-selected="true">
          All Works
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#branding" role="tab" aria-controls="branding" aria-selected="false">
          Branding
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#design" role="tab" aria-controls="design" aria-selected="false">
          Design
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#photography" role="tab" aria-controls="photography" aria-selected="false">
          Photography
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="branding" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="branding-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="design" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="design-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="photography" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="photography-tab">...</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="portfolio-title">
      <div class="row no-gutters">          
        <div class="sketch_block col-12 col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Cicada_BroodXIII_1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-12 col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.smith-mountain-lake-visitor-center.com/images_wallpaper/wide_screen_wallpaper/W4V4B4131_RONEY_PHOTOGRAPHY.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-12 col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.rachaelray.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MTI5OTcwMTkyNzEyMjQzNjc4-1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>       
      
        <div class="sketch_block col-12 col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/5a/13/ac/5a13ac1f76f5d033bb03b67412572961.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-12 col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/17/98/e0/1798e0883d42d34ae640a863e2d3126f.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
        <div class="sketch_block col-12 col-md-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://friendlysiberia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/DSC00738-1200x800.jpg" alt"">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  <hr>
```